# JMS with content-base filter

Tags: java, ibm-mq, spring-jms

Is it possible to do content-based filter with JMS?

IBM MQ publish/subscribe seem to allow content-base filtering
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKM8N_8.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bq13460_.htm
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKM8N_8.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bq13360_.htm

I've tried to find a way with my JMSListener to filter on a Body elment but I couldn't manage to make it work..

Comment: I believe that is [outside the JMS Spec](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncer/index.html).
`>The message consumer then receives only messages whose headers and properties match the selector.  ... A message selector cannot select messages on the basis of the content of the message body.` I don't know if there is some way to attach those proprietary IBM filters in some way.

Comment: IBM MQ can not filter based on the body, only based on message properties.

Comment: @JoshMc You are absolutly right, I tought we could, but I realise its only possible using Websphere Message Broker. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IBM MQ can not directly filter based on the body, only based on message properties.  IBM states that a extended message selection provider can do message selection based on the message payload, but as far as I know the only extended message selection provider available is ACE/IIB/WMB.

---

Please review IBM Knowledge Center page [IBM MQ 9.1.x>IBM MQ>Developing applications>Developing JMS and Java applications>Using IBM MQ classes for JMS>Writing IBM MQ classes for JMS applications>JMS messages>Message selectors in JMS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031980_.htm):

> A property value might duplicate a value in a message body. JMS does not define a policy for what might be made into a property. However, application developers must be aware that JMS providers probably handle data in a message body more efficiently than data in message properties. For best performance, applications must use message properties only when they need to customize a message header. The primary reason for doing this is to support customized message selection.
>
> A JMS message selector allows a client to specify the messages that it is interested in by using the message header. Only messages with headers that match the selector are delivered.
>
> ***Message selectors cannot refer to message body values.***
>
> A message selector matches a message when the selector evaluates to true when the message header field and property values are substituted for their corresponding identifiers in the selector.
>
> A message selector is a String, with syntax that is based on a subset of the SQL92 conditional expression syntax. The order in which a message selector is evaluated is from left to right within a precedence level. You can use parentheses to change this order. Predefined selector literals and operator names are written here in uppercase; however, they are not case-sensitive.

---

Please also review IBM Knowledge Center page [IBM MQ 9.0.x>IBM MQ>Developing applications>Application development concepts>IBM MQ messages>Selecting messages from queues>Selecting on the content of a message](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q023040_.htm)

> It is possible to subscribe based on a selection of message payload content (also known as content filtering), ***but the decision about which messages should be delivered to such a subscription cannot be performed directly by IBM® MQ***; instead an extended message selection provider, for example IBM Integration Bus, is required to process the messages.